# AmCharts force value axis width

Tags: amcharts

How do I go about forcing a fixed width to my value axis?  Since the size of the values of the two charts are significantly different, they don't line up on the left. Is it possible to force a width?

[image: AMCharts label width]

Answer (score 0):

So the trick to fixing this issue was setting autoMargins: false and then manually setting the marginTop, marginBottom, marginLeft & marginRight values.  marginLeft is where the adjustment is to force additional spacing on the left side of the chart.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here:

```
  const chart = am4core.create('some_id', am4charts.XYChart);
  chart.paddingLeft = 0;
  ...
  const valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
  valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.minWidth = 120;
  valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.textAlign = 'end';
```

We just set the chart left padding = `0` and a fixed value for ValueAxis label `minWidth`. Also do not forget to align the text in it.